# Complex filter using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a select called "Marcações" ("Tags") for multiselection.

The list in question is of patients.

I want to filter each patient taking into account that if the selected option is "Select an option...", the list of patients must be displayed in full.

If there is at least one select tag in the input, only patients who have at least one of them should be displayed.

[image]
[image]

```js
$('.patient-card').each((index, patient) => {
    const tagsFilterResult = $(patient).find('.tag')
      .toArray()
      .some(element => selectedValueFilterTags.some(str => element.textContent.includes(str)))
  }

  if (tagsFilterResult) {
    $(patient).show()
  } else {
    $(patient).hide()
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select-tag" id="select-tag" class="form-control select-search" multiple>
  <option value="" selected>
    Select an option...
  </option>

  <option value="AL">
    AL
  </option>
  <option value="Cod. Amarelo">
    Cod. Amarelo
  </option>
  <option value="RQ">
    RQ
  </option>
</select>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 1</p>

  <span class="tag">
    AL
  </span>

  <span class="tag">
    Cod. Amarelo
  </span>

  <span class="tag">
    RQ
  </span>
</div>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 2</p>

  <span class="tag">
    AL
  </span>

  <span class="tag">
    Cod. Amarelo
  </span>
</div>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 3</p>

  <span class="tag">
    AL
  </span>
</div>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 4</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried to output the value of variables via `console.log` or used your browser developer tools for line-by-line debugging? I suspect that `tagsFilterResult` can be an empty array and explicitly checking `.length` may help understand or you have to compare case-insensitive?

Comment: @PeterPointer

Yes, I've tried debugging several times but I still don't understand what the problem could be.

The value of `tagsFilterResult` can be an empty array.

It is its default value. ("Select an option")

Comment: One issue could be that the `value` attribute of your options is for example `tag2`, but the span with class "tag" has "2" as its text. `2` can not include `tag2`. So it is better to change the check to `str.includes(element.textContent)` if I read this correctly. If you debugged the values and the result of the calls you could see that.

Comment: Okay. Now the value of your option is the text, for example `value="Cod. Amarelo"` but the `span` with class "tag" in your example HTML is still just the number id of the tag. You will need to update that as well to be the text. You can change your code into a runnable snippet with the `<>` button BTW to help make debugging easier.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to update this part of the code regarding `span`.

I updated now.

Comment: I changed the code to the `code snippet` area (`<>`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257093/discussion-between-jose-guilherme-and-peter-pointer).

Answer (score 1):

You need to take into account that if `select` has a `multiple` attribute, then its `.val()` will be an array:

```js
$(document).on('change', '.select-search', function() {
  const value = $(this).val();
  if (!value || !value?.[0]) {
    $('.patient-card').show();
    return;
  }
  $('.patient-card').each(function() {
    const card = $(this);
    const isHasTag = card.find('.tag').toArray().some(el => {
      const tag = $(el).text().trim();
      if(Array.isArray(value)) {
        return value.includes(tag)
      }
      return tag === value;
    });
    isHasTag ? card.show() : card.hide();
  })
})
```

```css
.patient-card {
  padding: 8px;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border: dashed 2px #ccc; 
}

.patient-card p {
  font-weight: 700;
  margin:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select name="select-tag" id="select-tag" class="form-control select-search" multiple>
  <option value="" selected>
    Select an option...
  </option>

  <option value="AL">
    AL
  </option>
  <option value="Cod. Amarelo">
    Cod. Amarelo
  </option>
  <option value="RQ">
    RQ
  </option>
</select>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 1</p>

  <span class="tag">
    AL
  </span>

  <span class="tag">
    Cod. Amarelo
  </span>

  <span class="tag">
    RQ
  </span>
</div>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 2</p>

  <span class="tag">
    AL
  </span>

  <span class="tag">
    Cod. Amarelo
  </span>
</div>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 3</p>

  <span class="tag">
    AL
  </span>
</div>

<div class="patient-card">
  <p>Patient 4</p>
</div>
```